# Switch off the backlight of the LED screen of the android phone, while using it as a webcam via iVCam

Tags: usb, battery, screen, webcam

I have upcoming exams which shall be remotely monitored through webcam. Now the thing is that I do not have an actual webcam and I have decided to use my android phone as a webcam via iVCam (using USB, I do not have Wifi Adapter in my PC).

Now the thing is that, I use internet via USB tethering through the same phone. The exam shall be quite long and, during the entire time of using the android phone as a webcam, the LED screen backlight keeps glowing and I am afraid, the rate at which the phone charges it self through the USB of the PC, it discharges itself at a faster rate if I use it as a USB modem and webcam together.

So before the exam exam ends, I might run out of charge on my phone battery. So could you please suggest me some method so that I can somehow turn the backlight off while using it as a webcam to save the power?

Comment: You can simply disable the auto-brightness and change the brightness to the minimal level. The power usage of an LCD screen at minimum brightness should not add much current.

Comment: My LCD brightness is already set to minimum, but still within a period of time, there is net effect of discharge by a certain percentage and within 1 hr or so, the battery runs out completely.

Comment: What about using WiFi tethering instead of USB tethering? Then the USB port would be free for connecting a charger with a higher current.

Comment: Simply locking the phone should work. You can try DroidCam too.

Comment: I do not have wifi adapter on my desktop. So only USB is the option @Robert

Comment: Does DroidCam support usb interface? @CFCBazarcom

Comment: USB Wifi adapters are very cheap therefore not having one is not really an obstacle.

Comment: Yes DroidCam supports USB connection also. The problem is that the drivers or the phone does not always connect the USB debugging good and the USB connection does not work. When you connect through a USB, the USB debugging on your phone must be allowed and you must select on the notification "Allow USB debugging for this computer", select always allow for this computer. The drivers must be installed, if you have a problem restart your computer.